# Select average between two columns in the whole table

Tags: mysql, average

I have a table (for example):

```
price_from price_to
10 100
20 60
0 70
30 0
```

And I'm looking for the way to select average between to numbers in the each row and the average from the result value.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Average of price_from and price_to in each row:

```
SELECT (price_from + price_to) / 2 AS row_avg FROM tablename;
```

Average of each of the above row averages:

```
SELECT AVG((price_from + price_to) / 2) AS avg_of_avgs FROM tablename;
```

Average of each column:

```
SELECT AVG(price_from) AS price_from_avg, AVG(price_to) AS price_to_avg FROM tablename;
```

Average of all data (both price_from and price_to):

```
SELECT AVG(p) as total_avg FROM 
(SELECT price_from AS p FROM tablename UNION ALL SELECT price_to FROM tablename) dummyname;
```

**The above queries will return *integer* averages if price_from and price_to are both integers.** If you want the decimal averages in this situation, you need to use cast to convert at least one number in each of the column calculations to a float.  The queries would then become:

Average of price_from and price_to in each row (with cast):

```
SELECT ( CAST(price_from AS FLOAT) + price_to ) / 2 AS row_avg FROM tablename;
```

Average of each of the above row averages query (with cast):

```
SELECT AVG( ( CAST(price_from AS FLOAT) + price_to ) / 2 ) AS avg_of_avgs FROM tablename;
```

Average of each column (with cast):

```
SELECT AVG( CAST(price_from AS FLOAT) ) AS price_from_avg, 
AVG( CAST(price_to AS FLOAT) ) AS price_to_avg FROM tablename;
```

Average of all data (both price_from and price_to with cast):

```
SELECT AVG(p) as total_avg FROM
(SELECT CAST(price_from AS FLOAT) AS p FROM tablename UNION ALL 
SELECT CAST(price_to AS FLOAT) FROM tablename) dummyname;
```

Comment: @user889349 please consider accepting my response if it answered your question! : )

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT AVG(avgprice) as avgprice from 
(SELECT (price_from + price_to) / 2 AS avgprice FROM [Table Name]) as temp;
```